# Adding conditions to Triggers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I have these tables in my SQL Server database:

```
CREATE TABLE weather 
(
     weatherId integer Identity(1,1) primary key,
     weatherDate datetime,
     rainout BIT,
     temperature float,
     inchesOfRain float
)

CREATE TABLE weather_audit 
(
     weatherAuditId integer Identity(1,1) primary key,
     weatherId integer,
     date datetime,
     rainout BIT,
     temperature float,
     inchesOfRain float
)

CREATE TABLE maintenance 
(
     maintenanceId integer Identity(1,1) primary key,
     maintenanceDescription nvarchar(100),
     dateRequested datetime,
     dateResolved datetime,
     currentStatus nvarchar(20),
     estimatedCost decimal,
)

CREATE TABLE maintenence_audit
(
     mainteneceAuditId integer Identity(1,1) primary key,
     maintenanceId integer,
     description nvarchar(100),
     dateRequested datetime,
     dateResolved datetime,
     currentStatus nvarchar(20),
     estimatedCost decimal,
     updatedOn datetime
)
```

I want to set up a trigger which fires when a row is inserted into the weather table whose `inchesOfRain` is > 4. This is what I have now, but it isn't working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_weather_ForInsertUpdate 
ON weather
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF (SELECT TOP 1 inchesOfRain FROM weather) > 4
         INSERT INTO weather_audit (weatherId, weatherDate, rainout, temperature, inchesOfRain)
             SELECT
                 i.weatherId, i.weatherDate, i.rainout, i.temperature, i.inchesOfRain
             FROM 
                 Inserted AS I
END
```

So if I were to insert this

```
INSERT INTO dbo.weather (weatherDate, rainout, temperature, inchesOfRain)
VALUES ('4/21/2018', '0', '70', '6');
```

it would add a row to the `weather` table and also to the `weather_audit` table since the inches of rain is 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *depend* on your `Inserted` pseudo table to make the decision whether or not to add a row to the audit table - try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_weather_ForInsertUpdate 
ON weather
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO weather_audit (weatherId, weatherDate, rainout, temperature, inchesOfRain)
        SELECT
            i.weatherId, i.weatherDate, i.rainout, i.temperature, i.inchesOfRain
        FROM 
            Inserted AS I
        WHERE
            i.inchesOfRain > 4  -- just insert those rows with inchesOfRain > 4
END
```

Comment: So what i ended up doing shortly after this post was editing the if statement i orignally had cause i noticed i pulling the inchesofrain from the wrong place and changed it to So what i ended up doing shortly after this post was this: IF (Select InchesOfRain FROM INSERTED) > 4
and keeping the restr same and it worked perfectly. is there any difference from doing it this way to the way you did it?

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is all good, it just needs to be

```js
CREATE TRIGGER tr_weather_ForInsertUpdate 
ON weather
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

--Modified Code Start
DECLARE @inchesOfRain float
    
SELECT @inchesOfRain = inchesOfRain FROM inserted


    IF @inchesOfRain > 4
    BEGIN
    ---------------Modified COde End
         INSERT INTO weather_audit (weatherId, weatherDate, rainout, temperature, inchesOfRain)
             SELECT
                 i.weatherId, i.weatherDate, i.rainout, i.temperature, i.inchesOfRain
             FROM 
                 Inserted AS I
     END
END
```

Update: Marc S code snippet is the perfect answer.

Comment: Your trigger has a **MAJOR** flaw in that it assumes it'll be called **once per row** - that is not the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @inchesOfRain = inchesOfRain FROM inserted` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Wonderful! Makes complete sense. Thank you so much for pointing this out.